# IntegrityError when trying to delete User

Tags: mysql, django, innodb

I'm getting an `IntegrityError` when trying to delete a `User`:

```
IntegrityError: (1451, 'Cannot delete or update a parent row: 
  a foreign key constraint fails (`mydb`.`app_object`, 
  CONSTRAINT `user_id_refs_id_2656bb273656cb16` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) 
  REFERENCES `auth_user` (`id`))')
```

Using the shell, I could delete all of the `app_object` entries for this user using django methods, but it's still throwing this error when I try and delete from the admin site. What's going on?

Comment: I've answered your question but am unsure what you were asking. What do you mean by 'shell' do you mean a local MySQL instance? Is the admin site a different MySQL instance or just a different table? I assumed that you meant you were using two different MySQL instances.

Comment: @Danack I mean the django shell. This is a django-specific problem I think, I have actually sorted it by disabling foreign key checks while deleting, but I'm interested as to why it's happening.

Comment: It sounds like the user that you are trying to delete is referenced by another table. A quick way to tell is to try and delete the user from the admin and the confirmation screen will show you other records that the user is tied to. Delete those records (or re-assigne them to another user) then your delete should work.... or just use the admin.

Comment: @JeffTriplett I removed everything listed in the admin console, still get the same error.

Comment: The mysql database user, configured in django settings, has root permissions for that database? If not, this user can not delete foreign key costraint by default.

Answer (score 0):

First, delete all the entries in models which refers User model. Then delete the User entry.

Comment: The django admin interface is trying to do this for me, and failing.